# Update DataTables filter/sort indicies after fnDrawCallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, timeago

I'm using the [timeago jquery plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/) to format timestamps in columns of my [data table](http://datatables.net/). The `fnDrawCallback` DataTables option allows me to set / update formatted timestamps like:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

into a more human readable `2 years ago`. This gets called anytime there is a table redraw so it works for pagination, server calls, etc.

```
myTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "fnDrawCallback" : function () { $("abbr.timeago").timeago() },
     "aaData" : tableData,
     "aoColumns" : tableHeadings,
     "oSearch" : {"sSearch" : "", "bRegex" : true, "bSmart" : true, },
});
```

However, `fnDrawCallback` does not update the search indicies so querying `years` returns nothing. Is there a way to force DataTables to update its search indicies?

**Edit**

For clarity I initialize `tableData` and `tableHeadings` an array of hashes passed in through JSON. This seems to work fine, as this data shows up in the table without a hitch. The issue is that the Timeago modifies the DOM on the `fnDrawCallback` which happens after the filter / sort indicies for the table have been populated.

```
// tableHeadings === ['a', 'b', 'DateOne', 'DateTwo', ...]
for(i=0; i<tableHeadings.length; i++) {
    tableHeadings[i] = { "sTitle" : tableHeadings[i], };
    if(tableHeadings[i].sTitle.match(/Date/)) {
        tableHeadings[i].fnRender = function (c) { // closure over i
            return function (o) {
                var iso_time = o.aData[c].replace(/\s/, "T") + "Z";
                return '<abbr class="timeago" title="'+iso_time+'">'+'</abbr>';
            }
        }(i);
    }
}
```

So I can search for the `iso_time`, but not `2 years ago`.

Comment: Are you using server side or client side filtering?

Comment: can you please also post how you initialize "aoColumns"?